TimeoutError: page.waitForResponse: Timeout 50000ms exceeded while waiting for event "response"
import { expect, test } from "@playwright/test";
test.describe.configure({ mode: "serial" });

test.describe("Dashboard", () => {
  let sellerId: string;
  let userId: string;

  test.beforeEach(async ({ page }) => {
    await page.goto("https://ic.ewalls.io/");
    await page.getByPlaceholder("Enter your email").click();
    await page
      .getByPlaceholder("Enter your email")
      .fill("sridhar.fullstack.dev.india@gmail.com");
    await page.getByPlaceholder("Enter your password").click();
    await page.getByPlaceholder("Enter your password").fill("Qq1!Qq1!");
    await page.getByLabel("Show password").click();
    await page.getByRole("button", { name: "Sign in" }).click();

    const loginResponse = await page.waitForResponse(
      (response) =>
        response.url().includes("/dev/api/v1/user/getroutes") &&
        response.status() === 200
    );

    const loginJsonResponse = await loginResponse.json();
    sellerId = loginJsonResponse.user.sellerId;
    userId = loginJsonResponse.user.userId;

    expect(sellerId).toBeTruthy();
    expect(userId).toBeTruthy();

    console.log("\x1b[36m%s\x1b[0m", `SellerId: ${sellerId}`);
    console.log("\x1b[36m%s\x1b[0m", `UserId: ${userId}`);

    console.log("\x1b[34m%s\x1b[0m", "Login Passed ✓");
  });

  test("Media Size Test", async ({ page }) => {
    console.log("\x1b[36mRunning Media Size test [*]\x1b[0m");

    const mediaSizeResponsePromise = page.waitForResponse(
      (response) =>
        response.url().includes(`dev/api/v1/dashboard/mediasize/${sellerId}`) &&
        response.status() === 200,
      { timeout: 50000 }
    );

    const mediaSizeResponse = await mediaSizeResponsePromise;
    const mediaSizeResponseBody = await mediaSizeResponse.json();

    console.log(
      "Dashboard Media Size API Response:",
      JSON.stringify(mediaSizeResponseBody, null, 2)
    );

    const totalMediaSize = mediaSizeResponseBody.totalMediaSize.toFixed(3);
    const mediaSizeInMB = `${totalMediaSize}MB`;

    await page.getByRole("heading", { name: mediaSizeInMB }).click();
    console.log(`Clicked on media size: ${mediaSizeInMB}`);

    console.log("\x1b[34m%s\x1b[0m", "Media Size checked in UI ✓");
  });
});

This is my playwright code. The response is causing a timeout, but in the production web app, the APIs are working properly. In the playwright test, sometimes I'm receiving a timeout even though I increased the timeout period.
Running Media Size test \[\*\]

1) \[Google Chrome\] › eWalls.test.ts:129:7 › Dashboard › Media Size Test ──────────────────────────

   TimeoutError: page.waitForResponse: Timeout 50000ms exceeded while waiting for event "response"

   130 |     console.log("\\x1b\[36mRunning Media Size test \[\*\]\\x1b\[0m");
   131 |

   > 132 |     const mediaSizeResponsePromise = page.waitForResponse(
   > |                                           ^
   > 133 |       (response) =\>
   > 134 |         response.url().includes(`dev/api/v1/dashboard/mediasize/${sellerId}`) &&
   > 135 |         response.status() === 200,

        at /home/sridhar/Desktop/Sridhar/iris_frontend-Development/playwright/test/eWalls.test.ts:132:43

1 failed
\[Google Chrome\] › eWalls.test.ts:129:7 › Dashboard › Media Size Test ───────────────────────────
21 skipped
3 passed (1.7m)

Actually I am getting response data sometimes. I have to solve the problem and needs explanation why it was happening. Remember that it was working well in the production website.

before you login you are pressing button. What you need to do in order to make the mediaSize API to trigger?

Maybe you are getting response sometimes because the API response within the timeout and fails when time API response comes after the timeout. You can try to increase the timeout and see if it works.

You are missing await statement for media response.
const mediaSizeResponsePromise = await page.waitForResponse(
      (response) =>
        response.url().includes(`dev/api/v1/dashboard/mediasize/${sellerId}`) &&
        response.status() === 200,
      { timeout: 50000 }
    );


No still I the issue was same. But remember that sometimes the response is showing and playwright is successfully running the test
